# Microsoft sharepoint designer 2013 encountered an error during setup

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I know that this question has been asked before but everything I see is about installing the Preview version of SharePoint Designer 2013. I just downloaded the release version and attempted to install it but I get this same error with no more detail than that.

I have Office 2010 32 Bit installed and I am attempting to install SharePoint Designer 2013 32 Bit.

I have Visual Studio 2008 Professional and Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed and was wondering if that might be the issue. There is someone else here in the office that has both VS 2008 and 2010 installed that successfully installed SharePoint Designer 2013 but they also have Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 installed and I don't. Was wondering if there were components that were installed with that or VS 2012 that it may be looking for.

I should note that I have Visio 2010 installed as well. Don't know if this has anything to do with it or not.

Comment: can you share the error you are getting...also check thispost:http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/sp2013-problem-office-2010-and-an-office-2013-product-on-same

Comment: It's actually the title of the post "Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 encountered an error during setup." That's it. That's all I get. And the only option at that point is to close the window and the installation shuts down.

Comment: which version of window you are using to installing?

Comment: This is on a Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64bit computer